# Visual Basic - MSBuild Not Running

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, 64-bit

I am trying to build a program for x64, but I keep getting the following error messages:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2554,5): error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x64".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2575,7): error MSB4028: The "GenerateResource" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "FilesWritten" parameter. Object does not match target type.

MSBuild.exe exists and can be run, so I don't know why I am getting these errors.

I am using Visual Basic in Visual Studio Professional 2013 (Update 4). I am not using any DLLs, all I am creating is a standalone .exe file.

I've tried searching, both here and on Google, but cannot find anything helpful. Then again, I have a tendency to overlook things, so the answer has probably been screaming in my face for the last hour. I apologise in advance if this turns out to be the case.

Any and all help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Facing the same issue while building for x64 bit architecture. x86 on the other hand builds nicely

Answer (score 3):

replace 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe`

by

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

and try.it should do some difference.this occurs because the version on msBuild.exe has changed after update4 of vs2013.check for version differences..

also i suspect you are trying to build the solution in x86 architecture.if first solution doesnt work,go to the Build tab, change the `Platform target` from `Any CPU" to "x86"` and try. hope it helps.

Comment: My build environment is on a NAS system, and the machine I use isn't exactly the fastest in the world. It turns out that it just took a while to rescan the solution environment, because it managed to build just fine after I posted this question. However, I appreciate you taking the time to help me nonetheless, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this exact same error in a multiple project VB solution when trying to start a debug instance of one project.  By forcing a rebuild of that one project I was able to fix the issue and start the debug instance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by opening the project in Visual Studio 2017, instead of 2015